# ASP.NET Value from GridView textbox used in another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access a textbox value from GridView1 so that I can use it in another window called "BILL"

```
public void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName.Equals("Pay"))

            {

                    GridViewRow row = (sender as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                    //cannot use RowIndex

                    string fname = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtForename")).Text.Trim();
                    Response.Redirect("~/Bill.aspx?lblF=" + fname);


            }
}
```

This code is from the home page where I want to get the value from the textbox and set it as a string. When the button "pay" is clicked, the value should be transferred to the "BILL" page into label lblF's value.

When I run the program and click on the "pay" button it outputs error 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'. This means that the string fname is empty. But I am confused why?

html code:

```
        OnrowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#006699" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal"
        >

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forename">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Forename") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtForename" Text='<%# Bind("Forename") %>' runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtForeNameFooter" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>

    <Columns>
```

Comment: Give us more explain, we don't know what is problem ? accessing controls in another form ? or something else ?

Comment: No if even `fname` was empty string it doesn't matter to pass it to another page, but the problem may related to not finding `txtForename`, which line exactly got exception.

Comment: Meanwhile you are casting `txtForename` to `Lable` and in next line you are casting it to `TextBox` , if `txtForeName` is TexBox you can be able to cast it to Label.

Comment: string fname line had the error

Comment: Provide your design code also, this may `row` is null or can't find `txtForename`

Comment: I'm not sure what you meann by design code?

Comment: @A.King, it seems like problem isn't with `fname`, instead either your `row` variable is null or when you are trying to find control from it `((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtForename"))` is null. Do the debug and find it who is null among them.

Comment: Your row is not in edit mode and that is why you see this error. You can see detailed explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code that gets the naming container is returning null since the sender is a GridView. And that is why you get an error. The row is already available using `e.Row` in your RowCommand event.

Also,  when you click on Pay button,  the row may not be in edit mode. The textbox you are seeking is only there when the row is in edit mode. When row is not in edit mode, then the ItemTemplate control is rendering which is a label control from your markup.

You should check if row. `FindControl("txtForename")`  is null,  and if it is then find the label control for same column.  But,  you should give the label control an id in ItemTemplate,  which is right now missing in your markup.

There are other issues with your code.

- You are in `RowCommand` event when your C# code executes and so you already have access to the row by simply using `e.Row` and no need for NamingContainer logic.
- Also, `using(con)` doesn't serve any purpose if `con` is a database
  connection object since you are not connecting to any database but simply redirecting to another page.

**Markup with label control having an id**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forename">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblForename" Text='<%# Eval("Forename") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtForename" Text='<%# Bind("Forename") %>' runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtForeNameFooter" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>                
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# code to get the text for forename**

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Pay")) {
  //you don't need NamingContainer to get Row in RowCommand event
 //since its already available under the GridViewCommandEventArgs object

  //you can get the GridViewRow using the line below
   GridViewRow row = (e.CommandSource as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

  if (row != null) {
  string fname = null;

  //check if row is in edit mode by checking if textbox exists
  if (row.FindControl("txtForename") != null) {
   fname = ((TextBox) row.FindControl("txtForename")).Text.Trim();
  } else {
   fname = ((Label) row.FindControl("lblForename")).Text.Trim();
  }

   Response.Redirect("~/Bill.aspx?lblF=" + fname);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I cannot use                      
   'GridViewRow row = e.Row; '

Comment: It says GridViewCommandEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'Row'

Comment: What event are you having your code in? Let me post the video of how it works on my end.

Comment: I've added the event

Comment: Can you add markup for the button that gets clicked when Pay command is fired for gridview? Or better, if you put the full markup of your gridview so I can understand your situation.

Comment: I mean the html part of the gridview.

Comment: In your current html for gridview that you have provided, there is no html for the Pay button. At least mention the html for Pay button.